# Monit connection test frequency

Tags: monit

I want to have Monit check a web application's health, running a cheap/trivial check frequently and an expensive/nontrivial check less frequently (e.g. 1/5 minutes). How can I tell it to check a given host less frequently than every monitoring interval?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was looking at the [Monit documentation](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#configuration_examples)  and stumbled across this:

```
check process dynamo with pidfile /etc/dynamo.pid every 2 cycles
       start program = "/etc/init.d/dynamo start"
       stop program  = "/etc/init.d/dynamo stop"
       if failed port 8840 then alert
```

So you could specify any number of check cycles between checks for your expensive check. Configure Monit to have the check interval you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Run a second instance of Monit with a different pid file, different check interval and a different config file.
2. Wrap the expensive check in a script that will repeat the status of the last check until the next "expensive interval". Adjust the alert count to compensate.